# Is the dimensions of layers rounded up or rounded down when it is not an integer?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, convolution, dimensions

Sometimes it may happen that the filter mask of a conv or pool layer does not fit into the input volume.  For example I have a `5x5` input and a `2x2` filter mask and do not use any padding, while stride has the d value of `2`..

Using the formula:

```
H = 1 + (W - F + 2*P) / S
```

Where W is the input volume, F is the filter size, P is padding and S is stride - all one dimensional.

```
1 + (5 - 2)/2 = 3/2 = 2,5
```

What will be the used output dimensions? Will it get floored to "2" or ceiled to "3" ?

Comment: why don't you run the net and simply examine the log? you'll see there the output shape of each created layer...

Comment: Sorry, I am not experienced in this topic - I have not known about a log before. I will check it thank you

Comment: @Kev1n91 When you find the answer, you can (and should!) post an answer here yourself. Other people might be interested in it, too.

Comment: By the way, the dimension of the filter does not matter. Only the dimension of the input and the stride matters.

Comment: I will do as soon as I get to it.
@Martin Thoma this is not true, since the output volume is only for valid outputs of the convoultion. Thus a 3x3 filter will cut out at least a size of 1 if there is no zero padding

Comment: @Kev1n91 Ok, I assumed `padding_mode='SAME'`. But I assume that the behaviour doesn't change depending on the padding_mode and also that the behaviour is the same for pooling (where you have the same problem). Hence I would not make the question more complicated as it is only a simple calculation when you know how Caffe deals with the problem. (By the way, besides rounding up or down, there is a third possibility: Crashing. Did you try it?)

Comment: The formula for pooling stays the same. And no it does not crash

Comment: The formula you used to compute output size is wrong. You didn't consider `+1` at the end

Comment: silly me, that was a slip of the pen, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will get floored to 2 considering caffe implementation.
Line 18 of `$CAFFE_ROOT/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp`

```
 const int output_dim = (input_dim + 2 * pad_data[i] - kernel_extent)
        / stride_data[i] + 1;
```

Basically ,consider a filter of size SxS which is sliding on input.
As it moves at the end ,it might have to face an input equal to its size or less than its size.
If it is less than S ,then that part is ignored.This is how caffe implements it.